# Multiple membership model random effects specification

Tags: multilevel-analysis, missing-data, lme4-nlme, multiple-membership

We are looking at tournament performance of chess players over time and have a question about the random effects modeling for this. Specifically, every chess player belongs to at least one club, but some of them can belong to two clubs. Players play in multiple tourneys per year. We would like to integrate this into the model, but it is not entirely clear to us how we would specify it in for example lme4 in R.

Edit: Data example just to illustrate the problem

```
df_chess <- data.frame(performance=c(5, 6.5, 4.5, 3.5, 4, 8, 9, 8.5, 7.5, 4, 3.5, 3.5, 3),
 player=c("AD", "AD", "AD", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "MM", "MM", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR"),
 year=c(2007, 2007, 2008, 2007, 2007, 2008, 2008, 2007, 2008, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2008),
 club1=c("KNL", "KNL", "KNL", "KNL", "KNL", "KNL", "KNL", "BBH", "BBH", "BBH", "BBH", "BBH", "BBH"),
 club2=c(NA, NA, NA, "GEO", "GEO", "GEO", "GEO", "KNL", "KNL", NA, NA, NA, NA))

   performance player year club1 club2
1          5.0     AD 2007   KNL  <NA>
2          6.5     AD 2007   KNL  <NA>
3          4.5     AD 2008   KNL  <NA>
4          3.5     KA 2007   KNL   GEO
5          4.0     KA 2007   KNL   GEO
6          8.0     KA 2008   KNL   GEO
7          9.0     KA 2008   KNL   GEO
8          8.5     MM 2007   BBH   KNL
9          7.5     MM 2008   BBH   KNL
10         4.0     FR 2007   BBH  <NA>
11         3.5     FR 2007   BBH  <NA>
12         3.5     FR 2007   BBH  <NA>
13         3.0     FR 2008   BBH  <NA>
```

Considering for simplicity just to model the random effect intercepts and without a nesting structure: A model with

```
fit <- lmer(performance ~ year + (1 | player) + (1 | club1) + (1 | club2))
```

would exclude all players that are not part of a second club.

Is there any way to include a second club random effect in this model when only a smaller subset of all players possess this random effect (in addition to the other club), without losing all the ones who only belong to one club?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My response is coming many years after the original post. However, in case anyone finds this post in the future, it is possible to modify the `lmer` function from the `lme4` R package to fit multiple membership data. The details are on the following page:

https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/notes/multimember.html

---

**Edit:** there is now an R package implementing Ben Bolker's multiple membership suggestion as a wrapper around `lme4`:

https://github.com/jvparidon/lmerMultiMember (package is not yet available on CRAN)